How to call a function from a child class in an array of parent class objects in C++
I'm trying to make a game board out of a 2d array of Tile objects, a class I made. It looks something like this:
class Board {
private:
    Tile m_board[9][9]
public:
    Board();
    //Constructors, functions, etc
};

class Tile {
private:
    char m_type;
    //other class members, etc
public:
    Tile();
    char getType();
    void activate(); //This does nothing.
};

class BreakTile: public Tile {
public:
    BreakTile();
    void activate(); //This does something.

What I want to happen is that I can go to any Tile on the board, check if it's a BreakTile, and if it is then activate it. I have a function in the Board class that looks something like this:
void Board::activate(int y, int x)
{
    if (m_board[y][x].getType() == 'B')
    {
        m_board[y][x].activate();
    }
}

And that can activate BreakTiles. However, all it's doing is calling the activate() function from the Tile class - presumably because this is an array of Tiles - despite the fact that in the constructor of Board I define some tiles as BreakTiles so I know the tiles I'm looking at here are BreakTiles. I just don't know how to get the computer to recognize that.
I've been trying to see if I can somehow cast the Tile into a BreakTile, but I have no idea how I would even begin to do that. I'm fairly new to C++.

Use virtual. Also polymorphism only works through pointers/references.

This is not a [mcve].

If you make activate() virtual, you don't even need to check if it's a BreakTile. Just call activate(). In the Tile class, activate() will do nothing and in BreakTime it will do whatever you want it to do.

If you assign a BreakTile into an element in m_board it will get sliced. You need to use pointers (or smart pointers) as elements in order to store any derived. It will also allow polymorphism as mentioned above.

Note that what @PepijnKramer is talking about is more commonly called an "abstract base class" rather than "virtual base class". If you want to find more about them, that will probably produce better results.

@PepijnKramer: Not really a correction--I don't think "virtual base class" is wrong. But I'm pretty sure I've seen "abstract base class" more often.

Make a virtual base class TileItf (this is a good practice for unit testability and dependency injection later). Then derive Tile from this and add a virtual activate() to it (also have a look at C++ Core Guideline 128, virtual functions should have virtual or override or final).
After that, your board internal data structure can become a 2D array of std::unique_ptr<TileItf> objects, and you can create tiles and add them using:
m_board[1][1] = std::make_unique<BreakTile>();

(as long as BreakTile also is derived from TileItf).
Also, you can make an EmptyTile class that does nothing when activate() is called, and initialize your board with those (null strategy pattern, that way you will not need if statments to check if a field is empty).
Here is an example:
#include <array>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

// First define an abstract base class (or "interface")
class TileItf
{
public:
    virtual ~TileItf() = default;
    virtual void activate() = 0;
};

// then create overloads for any kind of tile you can have
class EmptyTile : public TileItf
{
    void activate() override { std::cout << "."; }
};

class OTile : public TileItf
{
    void activate() override { std::cout << "O"; }
};

class XTile : public TileItf
{
    void activate() override { std::cout << "X"; }
};

// The board now will contain a 2D array of interfaces to tiles.
// in C++ we don't use new/delete by default anymore, but use containers or smart pointers
class Board
{
public:
    Board()
    {
        // intitialize the board with empty tiles
        for (auto& row : m_tiles)
        {
            for (auto& tile : row)
            {
                tile = std::make_unique<EmptyTile>();
            }
        }

        // this next line looks simple but it does a few things
        // it will destroy the tile at the current position and assign a new tile to it. 
        m_tiles[0][1] = std::make_unique<OTile>();
        m_tiles[1][1] = std::make_unique<XTile>();
    }

    void activate()
    {
        // range based for loops (cannot go out of scope)
        for (const auto& row : m_tiles)
        {
            for (const auto& tile : row)
            {
                tile->activate(); // <== here the derived activate function will be called depending on the concrete tile type 
            }
            std::cout << "\n";
        }
    }

private:
    // Because tiles are polymorphic we need pointers to them (or you get the object slicing that was talked about before)
    std::array<std::array<std::unique_ptr<TileItf>, 3>, 3> m_tiles;
};

int main()
{
    Board board;
    board.activate(); 
}

